# MySql retrieve In and Out time stamp with sql

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I have a table as follows:

```
employee_id  location   datetime_stamp
21062        28.0       2011-07-12 05:00:00
21062        600.00     2011-07-12 05:05:00 *
21063        600.00     2011-07-12 05:39:48
21063        600.00     2011-07-12 05:40:06
21063        600.00     2011-07-12 05:40:28 *
21063        28.00      2011-07-12 05:41:23
21063        28.00      2011-07-12 05:42:52
21063        28.00      2011-07-12 13:14:24
21063        28.00      2011-07-12 13:15:04
21063        600.00     2011-07-12 13:15:23 *
21063        600.00     2011-07-12 13:15:42
21064        600.00     2011-07-12 21:00:40 *
21064        28.00      2011-07-12 21:01:00
```

I want to be able to retrieve the dates indicated by the * characters for an employee as an In and Out stamp from the system given a single date search parameter.

Note: One problem I've run into is some employee's shift overlap days.

Desired output:

```
employee#   In                   Out
21062       ???????????????????  2011-07-12 05:05:00
21063       2011-07-12 05:40:28  2011-07-12 13:15:23
21064       2011-07-12 21:00:00  ???????????????????
```

I hope this is a clear enough explanation.

Thanks for any insight you will be able to shed on this problem!

Comment: Are your 'in' stamps *always* (max()) before `location = 28` stamps, your 'out' stamps *always* (min()) after `location = 28` stamps, and always `location = 600`?  That is, do `location = 28` stamps mean the employee is working (or 'in the building', or whatever)?

Comment: Yes, your assumptions are correct.

Comment: I have tired to union two select then aggregate the results with a pivot table but I haven't been able to exhaust every case in a single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was unable to come up with a query for my specific requirements, I pulled the same data as in the format from above and loaded the output into an ArrayList in C#. Then I stepped through the array looking at the current and previous location of each employee to get an In and Out time.